# How does JPA @Version annotation works when you have multiple entities

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, transactions

Suppose we are using a DB with isolation level set to: read_committed
and we are also using JPA Entities annotated with `@Version`.

We have two transactions T and K like these:

**T**  -------------------------------------   **K**
start
read A
read B
read C
-------------------------------------- start
-------------------------------------- update A
-------------------------------------- end
update C
using the states of
object A and B
end

At this point in transaction T the update of C is successful, (version check is fine), so we are updating C using a status that never really existed on the 
DB.

What's wrong with my understanding ?

EDIT:

@Vlad

Consider this example:

T------------------------------------------------------K

Start transaction
Read A
-----------------------------------------------Start transaction
-----------------------------------------------Mod A
-----------------------------------------------Mod B
-----------------------------------------------End transaction
Read C   version = 1
Read B

// use data da A and B
// to update C
A,B -> C
// update is successfull (check version is fine)

End transaction

Using OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT your are basically telling me to
use always the find method with this option set right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimistic locking works for individual table rows only. In this particular case, the entity `C` can be updated successfully since the second transaction does not modify it.

If you want to create a conflict here, then you must use either of the following optimistic lock requests:

- [`OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-locking-patterns-how-does-optimistic_force_increment-lock-mode-work/)
- [`PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-locking-patterns-how-does-pessimistic_force_increment-lock-mode-work/)

This way, in the second transaction, whenever you update the entity `A`, you'll also trigger a version increment in `C`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I think it's not needed, but I would be glad to hear from you on that ?

Comment: Flush is called automatically at the end of the transaction, so you don;t have to call it manually.

Comment: I have one last doubt: suppose we load en entity wih hibernate findById with Option OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT and the we serialize the entity to a client (long conversation here), when the client gives the server back the entity should I create an attached entity, manually set verion on it and then call merge ?  sorry to bother you ;)

Comment: You are going to learn much more once you try all these examples through exercises. Use my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence) for that. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah I wouyld really like it, I'm also looking forward to read more from you ;).  In the latter example of the comment above do I need to call merge ?

Comment: Yes you do, but if you don't run this tests you'll never fully understand why. ;)

Comment: Yeah I would like to buy it from amazon, can it be done ?

Comment: You mean the print version? I have set up Amazon CreateSpace and I'm waiting for the final proof before I send it to publish state. I hope it can be available on Amazon starting from November.

Comment: perfect I would like to buy also to thank you for your time, Are these topics covered in details ?

Comment: That and even more. Check out the [Table of Content](https://leanpub.com/high-performance-java-persistence#table-of-contents).